# Assets 2 Upgrade - No Images in Manager and No Uploading

Tags: assets

I am running EE 2.6.1 and recently updated to Assets 2.1.3.

In the EE file manager, all my files are visible and I can upload new ones. But the Assets file manager is blank and gives me an error when I try to upload: "Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response. Please check the server settings."

I have tried updating the indexes with no success of resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your file upload directory paths are correct and run 'update indexes' from within the Assets module page.

Comment: Thanks, confirmed that file paths are correct (and all files are visible in the EE file manager). I have attempted updating indexes in Assets several times and have had no results. I am still unable to see any files in my Assets file manager.

Comment: Are you using a bootstrap to set your upload directories?

Comment: No, just a standard EE setup. I was running 2.5.5 and then last week upgraded to 2.6.1 using Updater. Then I updated from Assets1 to Assets2 also using Updater.

Comment: It’s possible this is related to _[this](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10774/assets-403-forbidden-on-all-requests)_. I’m also having the above-described issue. Navigating directly to `/?folder=44&ACT=16` throws a 403.